# Redirect to a specific private page with LoginRequiredMixin after login

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

When trying to access a private page, this view redirects to the login page if the user is not authenticated, and after the authentication was done, I wanted it to redirect to the private page instead of `success_url`, with LoginView configured for a **FormView**. When I access the private page without logging in, this standard url is generated according to django
`http://localhost/myapp/login/?next=/myapp/private-page/`,
in this case the url that will be redirected after login should be `myapp/private-page` instead of `success_url`

My code looks like this:

```
# myapp/urls
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("login/", views.LoginRequest.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_request, name='logout'),
    path("signup/", views.signup, name='signup'),
    path("private-page/", views.PrivatePage.as_view()),
]
```

```
# myapp/views.py
class PrivatePage(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myapp/private-page.html'
    login_url = 'myapp:login'

class LoginRequest(FormView):
    template_name = 'myapp/auth/login/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = 'myapp:home'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(self.request, user)
            messages.info(self.request, f'You are connected as {username}')
            # here the code to redirect to the private-page
            # instead this return
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
        for key in form.errors:
            messages.error(self.request, form.errors[key])
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Comment: Django comes with a [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). It stores the next URL in a hidden field. I suggest you switch to using the built in login view. If you decide to keep your custom login view, then you can look [at the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L69) to see how it's implemented.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem, thank you very much Djangonaut 